# Get current Wordpress page then add #post ID to the end

Tags: php, urls

I'm trying to find out the PHP code that will get the current URL and add a hash ID onto the end of it so a link can be generated and linked to.

The end goal is to create a link that returns: http://mydomain.com/news#postID-123. This should a) take users to the news page and b) jump to the part of the news page where the post ID of 123 is displayed.

Ideally I need a solution that can handle pagination within Wordpress, this is my code to get the curent page URL that I spotted on another thread but how do I create a new string from it?

```
<?php
$Path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$URI= get_bloginfo('url').$Path; // get the current web address for my WP site
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer should return: `` so from there you just do this:

```
$final_url = $URI.'#'.get_the_ID();
```

Which *should* echo `http://mydomain.com/current/page#372` which is kinda good for linking. But if your looking for a "bookmarks" link it would be best practice to do this (inside the loop):

```
echo '<a href="'.the_permalink().'" title="'.the_title().'">'.the_title.'</a>';
```

Which will echo "[Interesting Page](http://mydomain.com/current/page)" (note the title attribute gets stripped by the SE engine)

Comment: This is working a treat however it outputs a trailing slash on the end of the URL, before the post ID, this is what my outputted code looks like: http://localhost:8888/wp_thedistrict/wp_thedistrict/news/#145 how can I remove this last slash between news and #145?

Comment: The trailing slash *shouldn't* be an issue but if you use `get_permalink()` to store `the_permalink()` into a variable then use <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php">strpos</a> to get the offset then <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php">substr</a> to trim everything from 0 to offset (possibly offset - or + 1) then use the output of that in favour of just straight `the_permalink()`

Comment: I hope that made sense, and for whatever reason the linking didn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$jump_url = sprintf ('%s#PostID-%s', site_url('/news'), get_the_ID() );
```

Pagination is trickier. For any given post, you'd have to figure out what page it renders on each time you generate this link.